# In IdentityServer4, can you use "*" as the requested scope in a client_credentials authentication?

Tags: identityserver4

I'd like to set up IdentityServer4 to allow "*" to be passed in as the scope during an authentication request, and then the server will figure out which scopes the client has access to.
Is there an IdentityServer4 class I can override/implement that can "resolve/modify" the scopes that are sent in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to OpenID Connect protocol [specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest), all the `authorization`

> requests MUST contain the openid scope value. If the openid scope
>   value is not present, the behavior is entirely unspecified. Other
>   scope values MAY be present

However with Identityserver you can call the `Token` endpoint without scope parameter in the request and get all the scopes allowed for the client. `client_credentials` is exactly such a case, so you don't need any "asterisks".

If you would like to perform some "special magic", you can look into [ScopeValidator](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/da143532fcf99dcd26dee20709f68a521a07bdd3/src/IdentityServer4/src/Validation/Default/ScopeValidator.cs) as well as [ICustomAuthorizeRequestValidator](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/da143532fcf99dcd26dee20709f68a521a07bdd3/src/IdentityServer4/src/Validation/Default/DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator.cs) and [ICustomTokenRequestValidator](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/da143532fcf99dcd26dee20709f68a521a07bdd3/src/IdentityServer4/src/Validation/Default/DefaultCustomTokenRequestValidator.cs) implementations. The last two are the main (and the simplest) extensibility points for any request processing.

Comment: That bit in the middle about "without scope parameter" is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Initially I missed the second row of your question and that's the only place where you mentioned *client_credentials*, that's why the answer is more general. Nevertheless don't hesitate to mark the answer as "the answer". Thanks : )